# prevent zip archive download twice in two different folder

Tags: php, download, readfile, php-ziparchive

I tried to create a zip file using zip archive, it works fine although the zip file is downloaded twice in two different folders at same time, the htdocs folder where the source code is and the default download folder from browser setting. Is there any way that I could prevent this? I only want it to be downloaded once into download folder...

```
   $file_names = explode(',', $_REQUEST['files']);

   $dir = $_REQUEST['currentdir'];

   //Archive name
   $archive_file_name="Downloaded_".date("Y-m-d_G-i-s").".zip"; 

   //Download Files path
   $file_path=$dir;

   //cal the function
   zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);

   function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
   {
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $res = $zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE );
if ($res===TRUE) {
//add each files of $file_name array to archive
foreach($file_names as $files)
{
    $tt=$file_path."/".$files;
    if (file_exists($tt)){
    $zip->addFile($tt,$files);
    }
    else{
        return false;
        exit;
    }
}
$zip->close();

//then send the headers to force download the zip file
header('Content-type: application/zip'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($archive_file_name)."\""); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0'); 
//header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($archive_file_name));
ob_end_clean();
//flush();
readfile($archive_file_name);
exit; 
}
else{
    return false;
    exit;
}

}
```

Comment: You create the zip in the htdocs folder (PHP saves it there), that's the reason why it's there. You only download it once.

Comment: the code must be inside the htdocs to run it since all my php code is running in htdocs... is there any code or way to stop it generating the file into htdocs?

Comment: You can use just prepend a directory name to the filename, it will then be saved in said directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP script creates the zip in the local directory, which is your htdocs directory.

You have a few options now:

- Delete the zip archive after reading the archive with php (`readfile`)
- Create the zip archive in a subdirectory, if you need to save it for later (archiving)
- Create the zip in the temporary folder and delete the zip after use

I would go with option 3, as it will ensure that the zip gets ever deleted if the script dies before being able to delete it.

You can delete a file with the `unlink()` command. You just pass the filename or filepath to it and it does it (if the file exists). If you want to save it in a subdirectory, you just prepend the directory name with the directory separator to the filename. If you want to save it e.g. in the subdirectory 'downloads', you just add `downloads/` before the filename. `$archive_file_name="downloads/Downloaded_".date("Y-m-d_G-i-s").".zip";`

The better option here is to create the zip in the server's temporary directory and manually delete it, so the zip gets cleaned up as soon as it's done. You will get the server's temporary directory with `sys_get_temp_dir()`, which you can prepend to the filename. After you're done with your business you can just delete the file with `unlink()`.
`$archive_file_name=sys_get_temp_dir()."Downloaded_".date("Y-m-d_G-i-s").".zip";`

After you're done and want to delete the file you just do `unlink($archive_file_name);`.

Function reference:

http://php.net/unlink

http://php.net/sys_get_temp_dir

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and I had tried all of your suggestions. It will remove the file in the default download folder rather than the file inside the htdocs folder which I want it to be opposite. So i tried to manually put unlink('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\'.$archive_file_name ); to delete it but yet the result will still delete the file in default folder, not the htdocs..

Comment: That's pretty much impossible. PHP doesn't know where you're saving the file you're downloading. You are absolutely sure you are not saving the file you're downloading into the htdocs folder?

Comment: Oh dear, my mistake, I ticked around the browser setting minutes ago to save it to another default folder and now everything works fine! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

After download, you can delete the file on server:

```
(...)

ob_end_clean();
//flush();
readfile( $archive_file_name );
unlink( $archive_file_name );

(...)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it will remove the file in the default download folder rather than the file inside the htdocs folder...

Comment: My mistake ^^" I ticked around the browser setting minutes ago to save it to another default folder and now everything works fine! Thank you so much!!!!